# Function returns a list with two reversed copies instead of three

Tags: function, python-3.7

Can anyone explain why the function below only return a list with two reversed copies instead of three:

```
def multi_line_function(input1, input2): 
  input1.reverse()
  input2 = 2
  return(input1 * input2)
multi_line_function(['a','b'],3)
```

output: ['b','a','b','a']

Comment: Because you set `input2` to `2`.  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I expected the output to return ['b','a','b','a','b','a']. I removed 'input2=2' and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you assign the variable 'input2 = 2', in your multi_line_function.
Remove that line, and it will work.

```
def multi_line_function(input1, input2): 
  input1.reverse()
  return(input1 * input2)
multi_line_function(['a','b'],3)
```

Output: `['b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']`

Comment: Thank you Tino. I removed 'input2=2' and it worked. I  now understand the lesson behind this exercise.

Comment: No problem. You should select this as an accepted answer, if it answered your question.